# How can i extract particular text from Lucene Index?

Tags: lucene, apache-tika

I want to add pdf files in lucene index(probably i did). Now i want to extract particular text by lucene proximity search query.

proximity search query returns file names only.

> `But i want to extract all texts within the  proximity query range.`

Example Case:
test.pdf:--> "Sample text A xxxxx B. Lucene is great of all time"

proximity query is : A B ~5

I want to extract: xxxxx

How can i do......?

Thanks in advance for ur helps and tips...........

Regards,

SENTHIL SARAVANAN

Answer (score 0):

Please add while indexing file

```
            doc.add(new Field("contents", result, Field.Store.COMPRESS,
                        Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                        Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
```

here doc is of type org.apache.lucene.document.Document.

While Searching file please use  com.java.search.HighlighterUtil.getFragmentsWithHighlightedTerms(Analyzer analyzer, Query query, String fieldName, String fieldContents, int fragmentNumber, int fragmentSize) for fragments.